# How to make child process children of given?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

In my pid namespace I have an init process and bash process inside of it.
From bash process I start a new process (java1), so java1 becomes a child of bash.
Then java1 starts another process - java2 and that new process becomes a child of init process.
I'd like both java processes to have a common parent (which is not init process). I can not introduce any new namespaces and can not change the code that is being executed in the java processes.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Q: Homework assignment?  If not, please clarify your use case: *WHY* are you trying to do this?

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm trying to live-migrate those processes, so I need to dump their state (checkout) and then restore. I use [CRIU](https://criu.org/) for that. CRIU can traverse process trees and capture their state consistently but it seems like I have to make a rooted tree of processes to use it.

Comment: Q: Have you considered posting your question to criu@openvz.org?  Perhaps there might be a good alternative to making a "rooted tree of processes" to snapshot your process list?